# Angular build compression with gzip

Tags: angular, build, compression, gzip, iis-10

How can I reduce my angular build size.
I'm not sure how can I, should I use gzip for that?

Right now my main concern is how can I reduce my main.js file here is the build screenshot -  https://snipboard.io/LkJMSe.jpg, as my website is taking around 60-70 seconds to load here is total time to load main.js - https://snipboard.io/xGyRi0.jpg. I'm using a windows VPS with IIS 10 on it.

I'm not sure how can I do that I.

Thank you

Comment: One option is to lazy load as many things as you can, and make sure you're not importing more than you should from expensive libraries like lodash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gzip will not interfere with `Angular Build process`. It is a built-in feature in IIS. Enabling GZip in IIS is simple, just check the below options in IIS Compression module.
[image]
If there is no Compression module in IIS, please enable it in the Windows Features.
[image]
Please refer to the official documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831370(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
After enabling it in the website of the IIS, we could open the network tab of developer console to verify it, in the `“Response Headers”`, the `Content-Encoding` field will have “GZip” sign.
[image]
Besides, there are also other ways to reduce the bundle size, such as Lazy-loading, which is mentioned in the below blog.
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/optimize-angular-bundle-size-in-4-steps-4a3b3737bf45
https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: Does compression happens on the fly as user request?. Does it effect the server performance?, as I've only single core VPS.

Comment: It doesn't matter. As long as the website users are not too many,  it won't make too much difference.